# How do I know if do-release-upgrade has successfully completed?

Tags: upgrade

What is the successful storyboard for a `do-release-upgrade`? What should I see and is this documented anywhere?

I have a headless home server running 14.04 which I have run do-release-upgrade on.

Initially it bombed spectacularly, with continual spinning with this sort of error:

```
Processing triggers for dbus (1.10.6-1ubuntu3.3) ...
Processing triggers for resolvconf (1.78ubuntu4) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3~bzr0+16.04.20160824-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-firmware
 linux-image-4.4.0-66-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-66-generic
 linux-image-generic
 linux-generic
 initramfs-tools
 console-setup
 apparmor
 mysql-server-5.7
 mysql-server
 ubuntu-minimal
 snap-confine
 snapd
 kbd
 console-setup-linux
Error in function:


*** Send problem report to the developers?

After the problem report has been sent, please fill out the form in the
automatically opened web browser.

What would you like to do? Your options are:
  S: Send report (1.5 MB)
  V: View report
  K: Keep report file for sending later or copying to somewhere else
  I: Cancel and ignore future crashes of this program version
  C: Cancel
Please choose (S/V/K/I/C): S
```

Hitting cancel it would cheerfully attempt to continue with other packages (I guess) and from from what I could tell from other logs it would error based on lack of disk space in /boot.

I CTRL-C'd out of the do-release-upgrade and attempted to `dpkg --purge` a bunch of old kernel images. Unfortunately dpkg was in an invalid state and wanted me to run `configure -a`. But this would just try to rebuild the kernel images and run out of boot space. So I just manually deleted the kernel images, then ran purge, then ran do-release-upgrade again.

It meatspun for a while and got to here:

Setting up sys

```
temd (231-9ubuntu3) ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/dbus-1/system.d/org.freedesktop.login1.conf ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/dbus-1/system.d/org.freedesktop.systemd1.conf ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/pam.d/systemd-user ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/systemd/journald.conf ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/systemd/logind.conf ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/systemd/resolved.conf ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/systemd/system.conf ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/systemd/user.conf ...
Synchronizing state of ondemand.service with SysV service script with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable ondemand
addgroup: The group `systemd-journal' already exists as a system group. Exiting.
Removing obsolete conffile /etc/systemd/bootchart.conf ...
Processing triggers for dbus (1.10.6-1ubuntu3.3) ...
(Reading database ... 443846 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../lsb-base_9.20160110ubuntu5_all.deb ...
Unpacking lsb-base (9.20160110ubuntu5) over (9.20160110ubuntu0.2) ...
Setting up lsb-base (9.20160110ubuntu5) ...
(Reading database ... 443846 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../upstart_1.13.2-0ubuntu34_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking upstart (1.13.2-0ubuntu34) over (1.13.2-0ubuntu21.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../locales_2.24-3ubuntu2_all.deb ...
Unpacking locales (2.24-3ubuntu2) over (2.23-0ubuntu7) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libc6_2.24-3ubuntu2_i386.deb ...
De-configuring libc6:amd64 (2.23-0ubuntu7) ...
Checking for services that may need to be restarted...
Checking init scripts...
Nothing to restart.
Unpacking libc6:i386 (2.24-3ubuntu2) over (2.23-0ubuntu7) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libc6_2.24-3ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Checking for services that may need to be restarted...
Checking init scripts...
Nothing to restart.
Unpacking libc6:amd64 (2.24-3ubuntu2) over (2.23-0ubuntu7) ...
Setting up libc6:amd64 (2.24-3ubuntu2) ...
Checking for services that may need to be restarted...
Checking init scripts...
Nothing to restart.
```

It's been sitting here for about 16 hours now and appears to be idling. The console is not frozen - I can type into it, and the system otherwise seems to be fine.

A couple of processes seem to be pottering along idly...

```
  PID USER      PRI  NI  VIRT   RES   SHR S CPU% MEM%   TIME+  Command
24942 root       20   0  108M  7992  1160 S  4.7  0.4 52:29.86 @sbin/plymouthd --mode=boot --pid-file=/run/plymouth/pid --attach-to-session
27151 root       20   0  419M 68368  2788 S  0.0  3.3  4:31.70 /usr/bin/python3 /tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-cj48xujf/yakkety --mode=server --frontend=DistUp
28496 root       20   0  419M 66472   844 S  0.0  3.2  1:34.74 /usr/bin/python3 /tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-cj48xujf/yakkety --mode=server --frontend=DistUp
```

It seems to think it's upgraded:

```
# cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=yakkety
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.10"
```

I guess what I'm curious about is what is the expected output? I have never had a successful dist-upgrade before, I'm a little gunshy and wondering whether I should risk rebooting my system now and have it work, or just wait until I have a few spare days to rebuild everything from scratch, once again.

Comment: Sorry no one has jumped on this jus yet.  My 2 cents.  I've only done a `do-release-upgrade` once. Not withstanding the hoops I had to jump through after I rebooted to get everything working again, the actual OS update went the same as any other upgrade with a few added dialogues. On completion I was back at the terminal ready for a reboot (iirc). There was definitely no freezing or long waits, the entire process took maybe an hour at most.

Answer (score 1):

`sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Worked for me following a system-freeze during `do-release-upgrade`.

From [man dpkg](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/dpkg.1.html)

```
   --configure package...|-a|--pending
          Configure  a  package  which  has  been  unpacked  but  not  yet
          configured.  If -a or --pending is given instead of package, all
          unpacked but unconfigured packages are configured.
```

Following successful completion of do-release-upgrade, the dpkg command returns no response.